# How to remove date format from a line in a txt file using a Java?

Tags: java

I have a .txt file with thousands of line. Each line starts with a different date e.g. 07/23/1999. 
I want to write a program to be able to delete the date from each line. 
I'll be using a BufferedReader/writer and scanner. How can I find this type of date and deleted? Thanks in advance.

```
class RemoveDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
        File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

        String lineToRemove = "bbb";
        String currentLine;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to use a while after to delete the date from each line.

Comment: Just incase you are confused over Javascript and Java. They are 2 different languages. Will appreciate if you can post a snippet of your code and elaborate a bit on the problems you are trying to resolve so we can help you.

Comment: This  in Java. sorry for the confusion. `File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

String lineToRemove = "xzy";
String currentLine;`

Comment: If each date is the same length you could just use `substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for different date format and substring to remove the data depending up on the length

Example

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class DateRemover{ 

public static void main(String args[]){ 

String inputs [] = {"7/23/1999 data" ,"07/23/1999 data2", "07/23/99 data3"};

Pattern id = Pattern.compile("(\\w{1,2}/\\w{1,2}/\\w{2,4})");
List<String> ids = new ArrayList<>();

for ( String input : inputs )

{


Matcher matcher = id.matcher(input);

       if (matcher.find()){



     // System.out.println(  matcher.group(1).length());

     ids.add  ( input.substring((matcher.group(1).length()),input.length()));

    }

}

System.out.println(ids);

 } }
```